# Is it possible to get the exact time, when my iOS device screen is locked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to find the time when my iPhone device screen is locked, I am getting the status when screen is locked, but i am not getting the exact time.

Comment: No.  There's no notification for it.

Comment: `[NSDate date]` doesn't work when screen is locked?

Comment: No. There's no notification for it, but breakfree is an application calculates phone usage time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution this code will work in Background App Refresh and 
We can get the lock state when the application is in the background. We can run our code by Enabling any Background Modes, i am using Location Update.

```
int notify_token;
notify_register_dispatch("com.apple.springboard.lockstate",&notify_token,dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(int token) {
uint64_t state = UINT64_MAX;
notify_get_state(token, &state);
if(state == 0) {
NSLog(@"unlock device");
} else {
NSLog(@"lock device");
}
```

Comment: I assume this is private API? Sure looks like it

Comment: import notify.h apple will approve it